# Two types of suspension

Tags: suspend, laptop

I have noticed that the way my laptop (Dell XPS 13, Ubuntu 16.04, Unity) suspends when I manually order it to (i.e. via the graphical interface or terminal command `sudo pm-suspend`) is different from the suspension which happens when I close the lid. The most notable difference is that the power button continuously flashes in the second case, but goes completely dark in the first case. Besides that, I think wake-up time is also ever so slightly higher in the lid-close case, but I'm not 100% sure. I'd like to know why these two distinct suspension modes exist at all.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running?  And, which desktop?  Unity/Gnome/LXDE etc?  Finally, what result do you get from running `sudo pm-suspend`?  Same as using the GUI or same as closing the lid?

Comment: I added the requested information. On retrying suspending using terminal and GUI, my network manager still breaks down with this suspension mode. Hence I have removed that part of the question so that it's now only about the two suspension modes (and purely out of curiosity).

Comment: Start by reading `man pm-action;man pm-is-supported`